# Generating random 1's and 0's

Tags: visual-c++, random, generator

Following code produces equal number of 1's and 0's randomly which it suppose to do.

However, I am wondering how to get given %age of 1's and and rest is 0's. What changes I need to make in the code. Your kind response is awaited, please!

```
int random_gen::uniformI(int low, int high)
{
    int i;

    if (low >= high)
        i = low;
    else {
        i = (int) (randomperc() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
        if(i > high) 
            i = high;
    }
    return(i);
}

//main
for (int l=0; l<NUM_NODES;l++) { 
    wkey = nodes[i].WitnessKey;
}
cout<<wkey
```

;

Comment: similar questions asked several times on SO previously. Please try searching...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Knuth Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on an array initialized with the given percentage of 1s. The following implements it for 25%:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>

void shuffle(double percentage,std::vector<int> &l) {
    if (l.empty()) return;

    std::mt19937 gen;
    unsigned int N_Ones = static_cast<unsigned int>(floor(percentage*l.size()));

    l[0] = (N_Ones > 0)?1:0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < l.size() - 1; ++i) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> ui(0,i);
        unsigned int j = ui(gen);
        l[i] = l[j];
        l[j] = (N_Ones > 0)?1:0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned int N = 10;
    if (argc >= 1) N = atoi(argv[1]);
    std::vector<int> l(N,0);
    shuffle(0.25,l);
    std::copy(l.begin(),l.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,""));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that `shuffle()` uses an implicit definition of an array where the first `N_Ones` entries are 1 and the remaining 0. For a cryptographic application you might want to use a better source of randomness then the standard Mersenne Twister `std::mt19937`.